# Установка Debian

Tags: linux, debian

Установил себе Debian, в графическом загрузчике были проблема с подключением к интернету, поэтому я решил подключиться к нему уже с самой ОС. Но проблема в том, что ОС загрузилась без графической оболочки. Установить я её не могу, поскольку интернет не подключен. В связи с этим встаёт несколько вопросов: 
1) Как установить подключение к интернету (с примерами, если можно). 
2)Как подключиться к зеркалу для скачивания пакетов.
3)Как запустить графическую оболочку.

Comment: Проще (и быстрее, и полезнее на первом этапе, что немаловажно) установить ещё раз. А то начнётся: ой, а dhclient'а почему-то нет; ой, а я не знаю, как называется мой ethernet-интерфейс, и т.д., и каждая итерация вопрос-ответ по полчаса. Так что лучше потратьте это время на чтение https://debian-handbook.info/

Comment: Разобрался. Проблема заключалась в том, что в инсталлере нет драйвера для wifi, поэтому необходимо подключиться напрямую через провод. А дальше уже система сама докачает все необходимые файлы.

Comment: Если не трудно, напишите пожалуйста ответ и примите его как лучший. Только есть одна тонкость, которую надо бы уточнить: возможно, нет не драйвера (куска кода ядра, который поддерживает данную плату), а фирмвари (куска кода, загружаемого непосредственно в адаптер). С вайфаями в дебиане такое часто по причине закрытости прошивок (соответственно, они не входят в официальный дистрибутив и сложены в non-free).

Comment: Всё верно. Сначала проще будет подключиться к интернету через провод ,а после уже через менеджер пакетов или терминал(это уже кому как удобно) скачать необходимые пакеты в частности 'firmware-iwlwifi'. Плюс фирмвари для Ehernet Controller. Я посмотрел через lspci модель контроллера , скачал для него всё и вуаля - wifi работает.

Answer (score 1):

Подключаемся к интернету через провод. Далее через менеджер пакетов или терминал(кому как удобно) скачиваем firmware для Ethernet Controller(модель контроллера можно узнать с помощью команды `lspci | grep Ethernet` . Также можно установить firmware-iwlwifi.